# Localisation on Leaflet JS

Tags: leaflet, gps, localisation

I am getting my Localisation on Leaflet map using the extension. [Leaflet.Locate](https://github.com/domoritz/leaflet-locatecontrol)

When I am on my local server it works fine like shown bellow:
[image]

But when I am on a remote server I get this error.
[image]
How to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most browsers now disable geolocation unless you are connected to a secure server ('https' vs 'http').  This is a sensible precaution for personal protection among other things.

To over come this you need to connect to a secure server or, if you are developing the server yourself, you need to implement https.  To do that you will need to get signed certificates to authenticate your server.  Have a look at [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).  There are paid-for solutions available.